# How to Display(Show) inserted data on ListView when i create database,table and insert query on button's onClickListner?

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

I create database and table on button's click method(onClickListener),I also create Insert statement after creating table and it works perfectly. Now i want to show inserted data on next activity's listview control. I can't use SQLiteOpenHelper class for creating database and table but i directly create database and table using OpenOrCreateDatabase() function.

How to display the data in the activity's ListView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SimpleCursorAdapter to load the data into the ListView. You will find few examples in the ApiDemos (part of the Android SDK) under the package *com.example.android.apis.view*

[Here is a tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#cursor)